# Getting extra line from reading in a file with a while loop (scan("%s", &2dArray)) != EOF) in C, why is this?

Tags: c, while-loop, file-io, scanf

I am trying to read in a file with 35 lines of text, the numbers in the file are being converted to letter grades and outputted to the console later in the code.

The file itself is a text file with 35 lines, the first line being skipped in this code and the rest being read in,

examples of the lines in the file look like (the bold is what I am trying to read)

[Image of the file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qzoD.png)

```
601000002001010906001   5323 #0001 Y  S                AAAAAA AAA A        **1122334321135 113132311412413  **                                                                                                                                                                         009 
601000003001010906001   5323 #0001 Y  S                BBB BBBBBBB B       **12231342434321223333122142111 **                                                                                                                                                                          005 
601000004001010906001   5323 #0001 Y  S                CCCCCCCCC CCCCC     **24342323213151331233454432214   **                                                                                                                                                                        005
```

Attached is an image with the output, the 35th line should not be there. [Image of the current console output, line 35 should not be here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dEDiC.png)

My code looks like this (yes, it may be all over the place, I have been trying to fix this problem for a while now through a ton of debugging.

```
int getAnswer(char answer[][TOTAL_QUESTIONS])
{
    char c;
    int row = 0;
    int column = 0;
    char garbage[1000];

    while (scanf("%s", &answer[row][column]) != EOF)
    {
        // if(row < 34) {
        skipNchar(77);
        for (column = 0; column < TOTAL_QUESTIONS; column++)
        {
                scanf("%c",&c);
                if (c == ' ' || c == '*')
                    answer[row][column]=' ';
                else
                    answer[row][column] = c;
        }
        // scanf("%c", &c);
        answer[row][column] = '\0';
        row++;
        column = 0; //}
    }

    return row;
}
```

Why do I continue to read in an extra line of garbage from the file?

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre].

Comment: **Both** `scanf`s should be checking if they return `1`

Comment: `if (c == ' ' || c == '*')` - why not just `if (c == '*')`?

Comment: And sample input data

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help should generally provide a [mre] of the problem, which includes a function `main` and all `#include` directives, as well as the exact input required to reproduce the problem, so that it can be copied and pasted. The input in your image cannot be copied and pasted. Also, are all 35 lines necessary to reproduce the problem, or can you provide a more minimal example of the input?